# Horizontally concatenate cell array of strings

Tags: matlab

I wish to horizontally concatenate lines of a cell array of strings as shown below.

```
start = {'hello','world','test';'join','me','please'}

finish = {'helloworldtest';'joinmeplease'}
```

Are there any built-in functions that accomplish the above transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is too loop over the rows

```
nRows = size(start,1);
finish = cell(nRows,1);

for r = 1:nRows
    finish{r} = [start{r,:}];
end
```

**EDIT**

A more involved and slightly harder to read solution that does the same (the general solution is left as an exercise for the reader)

`finish = accumarray([1 1 1 2 2 2]',[ 1 3 5 2 4 6]',[],@(x){[start{x}]}`)

Comment: Thanks, it works, I spent the last 20 minutes trying to do it with vectorization - I can't remember the last time I actually have used a loop in Matlab :)

Comment: @Chris R: As you can see, there is a non-loop solution using accumarray, though you might not want to use that. Anyway, if the loop doesn't make too many function calls, it is usually reasonably fast in newer versions of Matlab.

Comment: @ChrisR: if you dont like the for-loop, you can write in one line as: `finish = arrayfun(@(i)[start{i,:}], 1:size(start,1), 'UniformOutput',false)';`

Answer (score 22):

There is an easy non-loop way you can do this using the functions [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html) and [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html):

```
>> finish = num2cell(start,1);
>> finish = strcat(finish{:})

finish = 

    'helloworldtest'
    'joinmeplease'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want is that these two are concatenated as a single cell array. Try using this code, works for me.

'x = [{start}, {finish}];'

Comment: the example variable `finish` was intended to be the **output** (the end result). It is not supposed to be part of the inputs.

Comment: Simple replace 'X' by 'finish'