# Combine columns row by row in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array 1300x6 that is all numbers. Below is an example of one row:

| 000 | 00 | 00 | 12 | 345 | 678 |

What I want to accomplish, is to have all the numbers in each row concatenated into one cell so that it is a 1300x1 array. I have tried `cat`, `vertcat`, `horzcat` and `reshape` but they all just merge the columns into each other, creating more rows. I would like it to look like this:

| 000000012345678 |

Is this possible?

Comment: are they strings? do you want them to be strings?

Comment: They are cells or doubles, and I would like to be able to use them as an X axis in a plot.

Comment: cells AND doubles I hope you meant. They cant be though, they must be strings, as you can not have 000 and 00 as a number, they are both 0. Then you want them as a string?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868841/horizontally-concatenate-cell-array-of-strings ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @AnderBiguri to clarify my earlier comment, it is a double array but I have experimented with converting it to a cell array. Also, I have tried the two options in the post you suggested; the for loop gets them all into 1 column but is a single column of multiple cell arrays. The other method just doesn't work, it throws a lot of yellow warnings and creates a character array with a lot of odd stuff in it.

Comment: I already explained why it cant be a double, not at least your example. However, it s better than instead explanations on what you have, you actually post a small example on how your data looks like. It is important that you read [ask] and provide [mcve]. If your your data is `data={' 000',' 00','00', '12', '345', '678';...}`, then the post I linked should work. ID its not, show us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with AnderBiguri that it is strange you would have 000 as a value in a numeric matrix, but you say it is all numbers, so let's go with that.

```
A = randi(255,[1300,6],'uint8'); %numbers
B = num2str(A); %characters with spaces
for ct = 1:size(B,1),C{ct,1}=strrep(B(ct,:),' ','');end 
C %characters without spaces
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted. Apologies for any lack of clarity in my question.